# Java Swing: GridBagLayout, how to squeeze 4 buttons to two columns?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

so in my japanel, I have a componenet which is 2 columns wide. I would like to add 4 buttons at the bottom not exceeding this 2 column. however, what I get is all 4 buttons stretch out across to 4 columns, exceeding two clumns. the cancelButton also has a weird horizontal elongation .

```
        gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;  
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbl.setConstraints(someComponenetHere, gbc);                    

    gbc.gridy = 2;  
    gbl.setConstraints(applyButton, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;  
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbl.setConstraints(cancelButton, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 2;  
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbl.setConstraints(applyAddButton, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 2;  
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbl.setConstraints(applyAddAllButton, gbc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to make you component 4 columns wide and stick a button in each column.

Failing that you could create a Panel containg 2 buttons and stick one of those panels in each column.

Comment: then it would be 4 columns wide which would make everything wider.

Comment: you can control the size of the panel independantly of how many columns it's layout manager wants to use.